# Relative path for Zend_Log in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, bootstrapping, zend-log

I am trying to work out the best way to configure my Zend_Log_Writer_Stream instance to write to a filename relative to my APPLICATION_PATH.

For example, with the following config:

```
resources.log.stream.writerName = "Stream"
resources.log.stream.writerParams.stream = "logs/production.log"
```

The normal way to init your loggger would be to either use the application bootstrap resource or do the following:

```
$logger = Zend_Log::factory($config->resources->log);
```

The problem with this is that the Zend_Log_Writer_Stream::factory method will try to access the file relative to the current script execution, not the APPLICATION_PATH.

As it's almost always the index.php inside /public that kicks this off usually it's not a drama, however when I execute individual scripts inside my unit testing directories it will use that directory to base the path on.

Ideally I want to be able to set:

```
resources.log.stream.writerParams.stream = APPLICATION_PATH . "../logs/production.log"
```

So that it always uses a predictable location. I would rather not have to hack the factory method of a Zend_Log inherited class to make this work.

I would love to hear how others have solved this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
resources.log.stream.writerParams.stream = APPLICATION_PATH "../logs/production.log"
```

should work. [`parse_ini_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) (which is used by `Zend_Config_Ini`) allows for the use of constants - but concatenation doesn't work like in PHP (with the `.` operator); just append the static string to the constant (you might need an additional `/` if `APPLICATION_PATH` doesn't end with a `/`).

Answer (score 1):

[`Zend_Config_Ini`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php) uses [`parse_ini_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) internally to read the *application.ini*. This means, it should parse constants. Please try with your ideal approach. Make sure the constant is defined prior to loading the *application.ini*

EDIT: Also see Stefan Gehrig's note about the correct format to use